# Building thinking time delay with time based tasks?

Tags: timer, jmeter, delay, timertask

I have this meter job for which I need to build some think time between certain HTTP Requests. But during those thinking time I still need to send a keep alive request on specific interval.

For example:

- User login
- get some profile information.
- Then he start to do some work.

each unit of work is delayed by some random delay varying from 1 to 30 minutes.
During that time we still need to send to there server a ImAlive request at fix interval (like 5 minutes).
Once the thinking time is expired which could be at 17m12s for example, then the loop exit.

Answer (score 1):

For simulate the delay you can use [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) which will be executed with given seconds you define the keep alive requests, inside  Runtime Controller add Timer as [Gaussian Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Gaussian_Random_Timer) to add delay between keep alive requests.

Comment: That is getting me much closer to what I want to achieve. I think.  so When I enter the "random ThinkingTime" while loop. I then created a "Runtime Controller of random thinking time in minutes, then I create a Gaussian Random of 5 minutes (interval for the keep alive), and just bellow the Gaussian Random Timer I put my HTTPRequest that is my keep alive packet to the server,   Is that correct?

Comment: Essentially Yes

Comment: Sorry I meant single controller and not while loop.  Also, how to make it skip the Gaussian Random Timer if that timer is bigger than the remaining time of the Runtime Controller ?  For example the Runtime Controller is set for 2 minutes but the heartbeat is 5, so I want to still wait 2 minutes but then no need for a heartbeat but instead just exit the Runtime Controller.

Comment: I think you need to add code, There's an enhancement of add JSR223 Logic controller for coding controller logic - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61711 you can vote on it

Comment: Thanks I voted!  In the mean time how do you suggest to do it until then?  I tried different ways but I’m still pretty newbie in jmeter scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) with condition like:

```
${__groovy(${__time(,)} - ${TESTSTART.MS} < 1032000,)}
```

Where:

- [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns current time in milliseconds since start of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)
- [`${TESTSTART.MS}`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops) - pre-defined JMeter property where test start time lives
- [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - allows execution of arbitrary [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) code
- `1032000` - milliseconds representation of `17m12s` - `(17 * 60 + 12) * 1000`

So children of the While Controller will be executed for 17 minutes and 12 seconds after test start. If needed you can add another condition just in case you want to exit the loop earlier. See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this will work for my case, but I really appreciated. I still learned new stuff from your answer and will make use of it immediately ;)

Comment: Does ${TESTSTART.MS} is the test of the whole tests or could be different for each thread based on the time each started? What I would like is the TIME since the thread started if available.

Comment: `${TESTSTART.MS}` is when your **test** started. If you want to get individual **thread** start time it can be done in Groovy as `ctx.getThread().getStartTime()` where `ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html). Check out [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for essential information on Groovy scripting in JMeter tests