# JMeter: how to stop the whole performance test after a defined time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'd like to, independently of any other config regarding amount of threads, ramp up time or anything else, just stop the test if it has been running for more than, for example, 2 hours.

[image: Thread group config]

[image: Runtime Controller config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have in Thread Group Scheduler Checkbox, when you click it

You can define Duration in seconds,

In your case for 2 hours enter 7200 (60 *60 *2)

Another option is putting all requests in [Runtime Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) with similar value.

You can also do scripting in While Controller with check time (similar to [Dimtri T answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516473/building-thinking-time-delay-with-time-based-tasks/47525231#47525231)):

```
${__groovy(${__time(,)} - ${TESTSTART.MS} < 7200000,)}
```

Comment: The Scheduler checkbox is the first thing I tried, but even if I configure there 10 seconds, it keeps running forever (until I stop it manually). I also found out about the Runtime Controller, but it doesn't stop the test either. I must be doing wrong something else, but I don't know what. I'll try the scripting!

Comment: Can you show image of your test plan and thread group?are you using JMeter 3.3?

Comment: I've edited the initial question to add a screenshot of the thread group config and the runtime controller config. In the thread group config screenshot, you can see that the test has been executed for 15 seconds and there are threads still being created.

Comment: Controller effect only samplers below. So it should be the parent of the samplers. I notice that you have more than 1 thread group so add scheduler settings in each.